# "WHERE 1 IN" Clause in SQL

Tags: sql, where-in

I am new to SQL and get confused by the "WHERE 1 IN" clause, my question is:

let's use the database from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_where) as example.

If I do query as:

```
SELECT C1.CustomerID From Customers C1
WHERE 1 IN 
  (SELECT COUNT(O1.CustomerID) FROM Orders O1 
   WHERE C1.CustomerID = O1.CustomerID);
```

What is the meaning of this query? Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This query is saying that the count of orders for the customer is 1.  It is perhaps clearer if written using `=`:

```
SELECT C1.CustomerID
FROM Customers C1
WHERE 1 = (SELECT COUNT(O1.CustomerID)
           FROM Orders O1 
           WHERE C1.CustomerID = O1.CustomerID
          );
```

The subquery is called a *correlated subquery* because the `WHERE` clause has columns from the outer query.  So, for each customer, it is counting the number of orders that match that customer id.  Only customers that have exactly one order are in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

It is checking to see if the `count()` returned from the sub-select returns one.  The reason is that you can't use `count()` or other aggregate functions in a where clause.  Writing it in this way allows you to make the `count()` part of the sub-select and, hence, we can check for the count in the returned value.

An alternative approach to the `IN` is to use the `HAVING` construct to move the aggregate function into the "right hand side" of the Select.

Comment: `HAVING` does seem like the proper approach.

Comment: I wonder if someone did this to force the query optimizer into a specific behavior.

Answer (score 0):

A meaningful way to write query will be using `exists`. You are just checking the whether the count is 1 in `sub-query` for each `customer`

```
SELECT C1.CustomerID
FROM Customers C1
WHERE EXISTS  (SELECT 1
               FROM Orders O1 
               WHERE C1.CustomerID = O1.CustomerID
               HAVING COUNT(1)=1
              );
```